# Is it possible to implement 'Continue as {Facebook user name}' button?

Tags: javascript, facebook, http, facebook-graph-api, iframe

I'm trying to implement Facebook login button for my site.
Some of Facebook products have a nice FB button that uses Facebook user name of user that already signed in.

And there is a question: Is it possible to get FB name using Javascript when user is already signed in in browser?

Example:

[image]

Comment: I don't think any of the SDKs provide this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can find it in Facebook documentation, section Login button/Plugin configurator: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button

There is an option: Include name and profile picture when user is signed into Facebook